# Android loopj + GCMIntentService sending message to a Handler on a dead thread

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement GCMIntentService in my android application.

When I tried to save the registration id in my database, the asynhttp showing the following error `" sending message to a Handler on a dead thread"`

The following is my code

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;


public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    ProgressBar progress;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    Context context;

    Integer flags=0;
    String regId;

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";


@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered at raj: regId = " + registrationId);
    tes(registrationId);
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    //Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = "+arg1);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "new message= "+arg0);
    Bundle extras = arg1.getExtras();
    String tat=extras.getString("msg");
    JSONObject jsono = stringToJsonobj(tat.toString());
try {
    String message=jsono.getString("price");
    generateNotification(arg0, message);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}


private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public JSONObject stringToJsonobj(String result)
{
    JSONObject jObj = null;
        try {

        jObj = new JSONObject(result);          

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

    }

     return jObj; 
}


private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, message, when);
    String title = "Test Application";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);


}


protected void tes(final String regId){
    ConnectionDetector cd= new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    String domain = cd.getUrl();
    SharedPreferences mPrefs=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0);
    String token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", ""); 

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams webparams = new RequestParams();
    webparams.put("fn", "loginProcess"); 
    webparams.put("email","username" ); 
    webparams.put("password", "password");

    client.post(domain, webparams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            Log.v("Start","Started-"+regId+"-User Id-"+regId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.v("response",""+response);
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                Integer status=obj.getInt("result");
                String message=obj.getString("message");

                if(status==1){

                    // Success
                    Integer success=obj.getInt("success");
                    if(success==1){
                        Integer registered=obj.getInt("login");
                        if(registered==1){


                            /* Session Save */


                        }
                        else {

                        }

                    }

                    else {
                        //setEr("Something went wrong. Please try again.");

                    }
                }
                else {
                    //setEr("Something went wrong. Please try again.");

                }



            } catch (Throwable t) {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
            //setEr("Something went wrong. Please try again."); 

            }
        });



    return;
}
```

Any idea ? Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error comes because you are doing Async call in IntentService, Make sure do use Sync Call in Intent Service, I had run into the same problem and resolved it by making Sync. See below example of Sync call in Loopj Lib.

**GCM On Register Method**

```
@Override
        protected void onRegistered(final Context context, final String registrationId)
        {
            final String userID = AIBSharedPreference.getInstance(context).getStringValue(StringConstants.PREF_USER_ID,
                    null);
            if (null != userID)
            {
                WSUtils.registerGCMID(registrationId, userID);
            }
        }
```

**WS Call for Saving Registration ID.**

```
public static void registerGCMID(final String regID, final String userID)
{
    final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    params.put(WSConstant.PRM_USER_ID, userID);
    params.put(WSConstant.PRM_DEVICE_ID, regID);

    AppInBoxWS.syncPost("update_device_id", params);
}
```

**WS Helper Class "AppInBoxWS"**

```
public class AppInBoxWS
{
    private static SyncHttpClient syncClient = new SyncHttpClient()
    {

        @Override
        public String onRequestFailed(final Throwable error, final String content)
        {
            return null;
        }
    };

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(final String relativeUrl)
    {
        return WS_BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
    }

    public static String syncPost(final String url, final RequestParams params)
    {
        return syncClient.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was also using AsyncHttpClient instead of SyncHttpClient and got the sending message to a Handler on a dead thread. Thank you so much sir